# In AWS with HLS content protection, where does the encryption key get returned, when selecting "NoStore"?

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, http-live-streaming, amazon-elastic-transcoder

In the Read Job Object, I can only find :  "encryption": null.
My playlist array in the Elastic Transcoder Lambda function looks like this:

```
Playlists: [
        {
            Format: 'HLSv3',
            Name: 'index',
            OutputKeys: [
                videoId + videoAudio600k,
                videoId + videoAudio1M,
                videoId + videoAudio2M
            ],
            HlsContentProtection: {
                Method: "aes-128",
                //KeyStoragePolicy: "WithVariantPlaylists"
                KeyStoragePolicy: "NoStore",
                LicenseAcquisitionUrl:"xxxxxxxx" + videoId
            }
        }
    ]
```

When I select "WithVariantPlaylists", the key is stored in the bucket and the encryption is working.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: Hey, you can see this answer, It might help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54146727/7393803